# Agenda not displaying last Date of any month

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

Description:
I am using Agenda from react-native-calendars library, it works fine with my data but its not displaying the last date of month in list below while I can see all last dates on month in header.
Here is my render method:

```
    return (
      <Agenda
        items={this.state.items}
        loadItemsForMonth={(month) => this.datalist(month)}
        renderEmptyData={() => this.renderempty()}
        renderEmptyDate={() => this.renderemptyDate()}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
        rowHasChanged={this.rowHasChanged.bind(this)}
        theme={{
          agendaKnobColor: '#f2f2f2',
          dotColor: '#185cb3',
          selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#185cb3'
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

It should display all dates correctly.But the result is:[image: Bug in calendar]

Not displaying last Date of any month in list below.

Environment:
"react-native": "0.57.8",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.24.0",